# Why is this angular email validation valid?

Tags: angularjs, validation, email

If you go [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.email), and try to input `me@mail`, you will see that the directive says that the email field is valid. Why is that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Domains do not need to have a dot in them. What about `localhost`, e.g.?

`root@localhost` is a perfectly valid email address. And if you give a name to your system (let's say, `mail`), then `root@mail` is valid as well. And if you also have a user `me`, then `me@mail` finally is valid, too.

Comment: Sorry that I did not specify. Exactly, I was referring to the missing dot in the domain.

Comment: No problem - I could read between the lines (at least this one time it worked ;-)).

Comment: root@localhost could be an indicator of a potential security problem.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

This wikipedia article explains thoroughly what constitutes a valid email address.

As you can see, many valid emails look very scary indeed, and probably don't pass many of the web's lesser validators.

In your case, the domain part of the email address (everything after the @), doesn't necessarily have a top-level domain. or perhaps it's entirely only a top level domain (i.e. postbox@com is valid)

Answer (score 0):

From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

"Note: input[email] uses a regex to validate email addresses that is derived from the regex used in Chromium. If you need stricter validation (e.g. requiring a **top-level domain**), you can use ng-pattern or modify the built-in validators (see the Forms guide)"